# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'runTest'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know questions like these have already been asked, but I could not find answer in comments to those questions. Please help me here.

I have the following page object:

```
class ChatInput(BaseTest):
    def __init__(self, driver, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChatInput, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.driver = driver

    def get_chat_Input(self):
        return self.wait_for_element_by_xpath(elements.CHAT_INPUT, 60)

    def add_content_in_chatInput(self, msg):
        chatInput = self.get_chat_Input()
        chatInput.clear()
        chatInput.click()
        chatInput.send_keys('')
        chatInput.send_keys(msg)

        return True
```

I am calling the methods from this page object to my test class.

```
from .components.ChatInput import ChatInput

class SmokeTest(BaseTest):
    def test_everything(self):
        env = self.getEnvConfig()
        for driver in env['DRIVERS']:
            self.configDriver(driver)
            self.driver.get(CONFIG.SITE_URL)

            self.chatInput = ChatInput(self.driver)

            assert self.chatInput.add_content_in_chatInput('Hello, this is agent QA. Please tell us, how we can help you today?')
```

But when I run my test, I am getting following error:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py", line 663, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py", line 590, in run
    testMethod = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
AttributeError: 'ChatInput' object has no attribute 'runTest'
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A class `BaseTest` seems not part of standard library's `unittest` package. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to test a method called runTest. Or more specifically, while testing you are tying to run ChatInput.runTest, which doesn't exist. That is what the error message is saying.

Comment: There is no method named 'runTest' in my code. Also, I am not trying to run that method. I am calling the method "add_content_in_chatInput()" in my test class

Comment: Exactly, there is no method called ChatInput.runTest, but whatever you are doing is trying to call it. From the information that you've provided there isn't really more I can say